# Syntax highlighting not present in duplicate closing modal

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, syntax-highlighting

Maybe this isn't a bug, but a design feature, but I noticed when voting to close a question today, as a duplicate of another question, that the syntax-highlighting normally present for the code content of the question/answer was not there.

Is this a bug?  I attempted to find a similar question I could use to base this off of, so if its already been asked, please close this question as a duplicate of that one.

Examples illustrating the problem:

Normal highlighting present in any question/answer(I used the same answer for both examples)

[image: Normal highlighting]

Lack of syntax highlighting of above content in the duplicate close modal window:

[image: No syntax highlighting]

I've only blacked out the url as I don't want to do any shaming by a loose connection.

So, is this a bug or does the bug tag need to be replaced with a feature request tag, and if so.. well, my only reasoning for that is its easier to read.

Comment: @TinyGiant The code snippet origin is not what I'm hiding; I'm hiding the url of the question I'd be closing as a duplicate, so unless you're referring to that, I'm fairly certain you didn't find it.